# How do i print out the names of the items inputted?

Tags: c

i'm new to programming so i'm having a hard time figuring out how to output the names of the items inputted in my loop, all other calculations are executing but i keep getting unknown values when the names of the item is outputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
 {
int count,num,a;
char *item [15][100];
float price,net_total, tax, total_pay,grandT;

do{
printf("Please enter the name of the item:");scanf("%s",&item[a]);
printf("\n");
printf("Please enter the price of the item: $");scanf("%f",&price);
        
net_total+=price;
tax=0.14*net_total;
grandT=net_total+tax;

printf("\nSelect '1' to continue or '0' to exit:\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
count++;
}
while (num!=0);
system ("cls");
printf("\tSummary Information of Items purchsed\n");
printf("Name(s)of the item(s) purchased: \t%s\n ",item[a]); 
printf("Net total:\t$%.2f\n",net_total);
printf("Total tax:\t$%.2f\n",tax);
printf("Total payable:\t$%.2f\n ",grandT);

    
}`
```

Comment: `item[a]` You never initialise nor even set `a`. Similarly you don't initialise `count` and `net_total`. So lots of undefined behaviour.

Comment: `char *item [15][100];`? I'm guessing what you really want is `char item [15][100];`

Comment: You are new to programming, that's good. One of the first thing to learn is how to format your code (indentation) so that his structure becomes clear. It is particularly useful on StackOverflow because you want the we understand your code.

Comment: You can refer the doc below on how to format question before asking on StackOverflow :- 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

1/ You should indent your code so it becomes easier to read.
2/ You didn't initialize `a`, `count` and `net_total`.  (`a` is an index from `0` to `15`).
3/ `char item [15][100]`

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main()
    {
      int count=0,num,a=0;
      char item [15][100];
      float price,net_total=0, tax, total_pay,grandT;
    
      do
        {
          printf("Please enter the name of the item:");
          scanf("%s",&item[a]);
          printf("\n");
          printf("Please enter the price of the item: $");
          scanf("%f",&price);
          net_total+=price;
          tax=0.14*net_total;
          grandT=net_total+tax;
          
          printf("\nSelect '1' to continue or '0' to exit:\n");
          scanf("%d",&num);
          count++;
    
     
        }
      while (num!=0);
      system ("cls");
      printf("\tSummary Information of Items purchsed\n");
      printf("Name(s)of the item(s) purchased: \t%s\n ",item[a]); 
      printf("Net total:\t$%.2f\n",net_total);
      printf("Total tax:\t$%.2f\n",tax);
      printf("Total payable:\t$%.2f\n ",grandT);
   }
```

Comment: In your numbered list, at number 3, you may want to write a proper sentence, in order to specify what exactly is wrong.